# What is the bit memory task?

Tags: transformer, attention, memory

I learned from [this post](https://read.deeplearning.ai/the-batch/issue-102/) about the so-called bit memory:

> They froze its self-attention and feed-forward layers and, in separate copies, fine-tuned peripheral layers on each on a wide range of tasks: Bit memory (memorizing strings of bits), Bit XOR (performing logical operations on pairs of strings of bits), ListOps (parsing and performing mathematical operations), MNIST, CIFAR-10 (classification of images), CFAR-10 LRA (classification of flattened, greyscale images), and remote homology detection (predicting what kind of protein structure an amino acid is part of).

I wonder what the "bit memory" task is? Is it an identity function as described in [this post](https://krbnite.github.io/Deep-Learning-Nanodegree-Notes-on-Autoencoders/)? Or the [memory network](https://paperswithcode.com/method/memory-network)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read the paper. It tells you.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.05247.pdf) (page 3)

> **Bit memory.** Similar to the task proposed by Miconi et al. (2018), we consider a bit memory
> task where the model is shown 5 bitstrings each of length 1000. Afterwards, the model is shown
> a masked version of one of the bitstrings, where each bit is masked with probability 0.5, and the
> model is tasked with producing the original bitstring. The bitstrings are broken up into sequences of
> length 50, so that the models are fed 120 tokens of dimension 50.

It wasn't immediately clear to me whether they train the model on the bitstrings (in which case 5 is quite low and a Transformer model is not required) or just present them to it when running the model. Figure 4 (page 8) makes it clear that it's the latter, as the original bitstrings and the query both appear on the same attention plot.

i.e. the input is something like:

```
00011110011100100001000101110011...
01000101001101100011001110010110...
11000101111111001010011010111010...
01011101001100100011111000000100...
11110100011010011000101100010101...
query
*10**10*1**1110*****0110**11**1*...
```